# Component which dependent from other components with different scopes (component hierarchies with different scopes)

Tags: dependency-injection, composition, dagger-2

I have complex multi-tier architecture in my Android project.

Currently i want to use the following structure of the DI components and modules:

```
[Data Layer]
    @DataScope //scope is used for caching (Singleton) some Data Layer entities for whole application
    - DataComponent //exposes just interfaces which should be used on the BL Layer
        //Modules exposes entities for internal (Data Layer) injections and entities which exposed by DataComponent for BL Layer
        * DataModule1
        * DataModule2
        * DataModule3

[Business Logic Layer] (also has component dependency on DataComponent)
    @BlScope //scope is used for caching (Singleton) some BL Layer entities for whole application
    - BlComponent //exposes just interfaces which should be used on the Service Layer & Presentation Layer
        //Modules exposes entities for internal (BL Layer) injections and entities which exposed by BLComponent for the Service Layer & Presentation Layer
        * BlModule1
        * BlModule2

[Service Layer] (also has component dependency on BlComponent) - this layer has Android specific entities (Android Service, ContentProvider) not related to the Presentation Layer
    @ServiceScope //scope is used for caching (Singleton) some Service Layer entities for whole application
    - ServiceComponent //exposes just interfaces which should be used on the Presentation Layer
        * ServiceModule //Module exposes entities for internal (Service Layer) injections and entities which exposed by ServiceComponent for the Presentation Layer

[Presentation Layer] (also has component dependency on: ServiceComponent, BlComponent)
    @PresentationScope //scope is used for caching (Singleton) some Presentation Layer entities for whole application
    - PresentationComponent //exposes just interfaces which should be used on the current layer
        * PresentationModule //Module exposes entities injections on the current layer
```

The ServiceComponent & BlComponent don't expose the similar interfaces.

To build the main graph i use the following code:

```
DataComponent dataComponent = DaggerDataComponent.builder().<addModules>.build();
BlComponent dataComponent = DaggerBlComponent.builder().<addModules>.dataComponent(dataComponent).build();
ServiceComponent serviceComponent = DaggerServiceComponent.builder().<addModule>.blComponent(blComponent).build();
PresentationComponent presentationComponent = DaggerPresentationComponent.builder().<addModule>.blComponent(blComponent).serviceComponent(serviceComponent).build();
```

In the PresentationLayer i use only "presentationComponent" to provide required dependencies from ServiceComponent/Layer and BLComponent/Layer.

Currently scenario above doesn't work, because PresentationComponent depends on the 2 scoped components with the error

> "...depends on more than one scoped component:..."

Though it allows to use one scoped component with many non-scoped components. This architecture is directed to restrict to use internal layer entities on the upper layers and in the same time to have independent tests (unit & instrumentation) on each layer/module.

Could anybody help me to understand is it bug or desirable behavior of the Dagger processor? (and why?)
Issue on the Dagger2 repo: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/747#issuecomment-303526785

Answer (score 4):

This is no longer an issue in later version of Dagger 2 as per the fix [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/715bdd72db06c2cdc7717dc5adcf6aa6827b8a50)

On older versions of Dagger 2, it is possible to work around the problem by declaring components that depend on supertypes of Dagger components as per the GitHub example [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1225#issuecomment-405602591):

```
interface AppComponent {
  App app();
}

@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
interface RequestComponent { ... }

@Component
interface EnglishAppComponent extends AppComponent {}

@Component
interface SpanishAppComponent extends AppComponent {}
```

Comment: I disagree with you, in fact we can use diamond dependency with multiple components (but only one dependency component may be scoped) and project compiles without any error. The main aim - avoid cyclic dependencies, and similar dependencies from components to avoid diamond problem (in your example graph - we should avoid similar exposed interfaces for B & C components.

Comment: In my case each Component has multiple modules, but component contract exposes only interfaces which can be used in upper layer (form of encapsulation of the internal layer dependencies provided by layer modules), so if Service Component (ServiceScope) doesn't expose the same interfaces as BL Component (BlScope), why the PresentationComponent can't use of both? (and again, if i remove scope from the ServiceComponent - all things works well)