# Dagger 2 - Component depends on two components

Tags: dagger-2

**Question: How to build a CoffeeComponent based on dependencies in `BeansComponent` and `WaterComponent` using Dagger 2?**

`ApplicationComponent <- @modules = Earth.module
       |           |
BeansComponent   WaterComponent
       \          /
      CoffeeComponent`

**Requirements:** `BeansComponent` and `WaterComponent` have individual scopes.

**Solution so far**:

`BeansComponent` would be a Subcomponent of `ApplicationComponent`

`WaterComponent` would be a Subcomponent of `ApplicationComponent`

`ApplicationComponent` uses `EarthModule`

`WaterComponent` and `BeansComponent` use dependencies from `ApplicationComponent (EarthModule)`

It's possible to include all Modules of `BeansComponent` and `WaterComponent` together in `WaterBeansComponent` and create `CoffeeComponent` as a Subcomponent of `WaterBeansComponent`. But different scopes are not possible this way.

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple inheritance in scopes like that. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44157859/5241933)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks for that. Would you like to reference this in an accepted answer or should i close it?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I'll write an answer for you when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger 2 doesn't support mixing of scopes in the manner outlined in the diagram. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44157859/5241933) for an attempted explanation why.

Moreover, if you structure your app correctly you shouldn't need scope multiple inheritance. Scopes and Components track *lifecycles* so it doesn't make much sense for a subcomponent to track two sibling lifecycles.

The separation of concerns you are looking for is probably better achieved using modules. First use modules to group by functionality. Then reason about the lifecycles of the dependencies that will be bound in the modules and use this knowledge to compose components from your modules.