# Dagger2 Component depends on more than one scoped component

Tags: android, dagger-2

Hey I have three components:

- Application -> provide Context (e.g. LocationUsecase)
- ApiService ->    provide Retrofit (Rest calls)
- DBService -> provide RoomDB (save in    SQLite)

Sometimes I want to use more than one component in my ViewModel
 - but I run into exception where I may not `.inject(ViewModel)` the same class to many components.

```
UserViewModel{
   @Inject ApiService api;
   @Inject DatabaseService db;

   public User(){
     Application.getApiComponent.inject(this)
     Application.getDBComponent.inject(this)
  }

}
```

Because I want to have components decopuled (for testing purpose)
I decided to add dependencies to my ApplicationComponent, and when Injecting into Application to be able to use albo DB, and REST

```
@PerApplication
@Component(dependencies = {DBComponent.class, RestApiComponent.class},
        modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent{...}

@DbScope
@Component(modules = {DBModule.class})
public interface DBComponent {...}

@RestScope
@Component(modules = {RestApiRetrofitModule.class})
public interface RestApiComponent {...}
```

This time I run into compile ERROR:

*PerApplication ApplicationComponent depends on more than one scoped component:
@DbScope DBComponent
@RestScope RestApiComponent*

The problem is that I've not found ANY exemple when people use more then one depencecies - is it restriced?
When I remove **@Scope** of DBComponent it's fine - but I have unscoped instance that will return every time new instance
When I remove one component from dependencies i will also build without error.

How I'm able to use two dependencies in my Component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there - the `dependencies =` needs to go in the dependent (child) components

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent{...}

@DbScope
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = DBModule.class)
public interface DBComponent {...}

@RestScope
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = RestApiRetrofitModule.class)
public interface RestApiComponent {...}
```

Now just make sure you are exposing the dependencies that are bound in the module set for `ApplicationComponent` so that the dependent components can use them.

So if you bind a `SharedPreferences` at `ApplicationComponent` level and you want that dependency to be shared with the dependent components you will need to write a provision method in the `ApplicationComponent`

```
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent { 

    SharedPreferences exposeSharedPreferences();  
}
```

Also, you might want to reconsider making scopes just for DB and REST - these are more like groupings of functionality and the decoupling you desire can be accomplished with modules.

You normally only need a few scopes in an Android app - an `@PerApp` and a `@PerActivity` scope since scopes track lifecycles and these are the two main lifecycles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In your example DBScope become parent scope of PerApplication? And when initializing Dagger_DBComponent.builder I will get scope from child (ApplicationComponent)?
It's nice way around, I will try it as soon as possible, but questions remains: "Is it possible to use more than one dependencies?"

Comment: @murt to directly answer your question, it is not possible to have a component that depends on more than one scoped component. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178673/5241933) for an explanation why

Comment: Also, in the example `@PerApplication` is the root scope. `@DbScope` and `@RestScope` would be narrower scopes

Comment: @DavidRawson it's a bit weird 'cuz normally you want to isolate your base modules (e.g. net, repo, ops) from knowing every single dependency from an app-level module. Actually, I stuck with this issue, 'cuz in my project I've got about a dozen components (one per project module) and they form a tree where the root is the app component but now the only way to have singleton dependencies in base components is to implement them as real singletons.

Comment: "[if] you want that dependency to be shared with the dependent components you will need to write a provision method..." - this was the key I was missing when working with component dependencies. Thank you x1000!