# Dagger2 - application can't depend on more than one scoped component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

*NB This question might be similar to other questions but It provides a better explanation with accessory code and aims to find a solution to the problem, the solutions provided in other questions are not suitable.*

Just a few days ago I started to develop an Android modular application. I use Dagger 2 in order to handle dependency injection and I'm currently facing a weird behaviour.
I've got my main application module, and three other modules:

- `Core_Module`: it exposes third-party libraries and storage layer.
- `Localisation_Module`: it exposes a repository in order get localised informations.
- `Configuration_Module`: it exposes a repository in order to get configuration parameters.

Both `Configuration_Module` and `Localisation_Module` depend on `Core_Module`.

CoreComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class, NetworkingModule::class, RepositoryModule::class])
interface CoreComponent {
    @Named("retrofit")
    fun retrofit(): Retrofit

    @Named("retrofitWithCache")
    fun retrofitWithCache(): Retrofit

    fun storageRepository(): StorageRepository
}
```

LocalisationComponent:

```
@Component(modules = [ServiceModule::class, RepositoryModule::class], dependencies = [CoreComponent::class])
@LocalisationScope
interface LocalisationComponent {
    fun localisationService(): LocalisationService
    fun localisationRepository(): LocalisationRepository
}
```

ConfigurationComponent

```
@Component(modules = [ServiceModule::class, RepositoryModule::class], dependencies = [CoreComponent::class])
@ConfigurationScope
interface ConfigurationComponent {
    fun configurationService(): ConfigurationService
    fun configurationRepository(): ConfigurationRepository
}
```

ApplicationComponent

```
@Component(dependencies = [LocalisationComponent::class, ConfigurationComponent::class])
@ApplicationScope
abstract class ApplicationComponent {
    abstract fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

MainApplication

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        this.registerDependencies()
    }

    private fun registerDependencies() {
        val coreModule = CoreModule(applicationContext)
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .localisationComponent(LocalisationModule(coreModule).localisationComponent)
                .configurationComponent(ConfigurationModule(coreModule).configurationComponent)
                .build()
    }
}
```

I decided to design this architecture because I want to separate functionality into independent, interchangeable modules, so that each contains everything necessary to execute a specific functionality and export single modules to other applications.

[image]

Unfortunately I got an error saying that Dagger component is not allowed to depend on multiple scoped components.
Does anyone know how to face this kind of issue?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157859/component-which-dependent-from-other-components-with-different-scopes-component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component which dependent from other components with different scopes (component hierarchies with different scopes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157859/component-which-dependent-from-other-components-with-different-scopes-component)

Comment: 'LocalisationComponent' and 'ConfigurationComponent' should also be '@Singleton'.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer. Unfortunately the solutions proposed are not suitable for this situation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of troubles, I found a solution suitable for my case. All the modules described (`Configuration_Module`, `Localisation_Module`) need to be used inside my Application module.

So for the `@ApplicationScope` `@Module` called `ApplicationModule` I removed all the component dependecies.

Application Component

```
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
@ApplicationScope
abstract class ApplicationComponent {
    abstract fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

Application Module

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val localisationComponent: LocalisationComponent,
                        private val configurationComponent: ConfigurationComponent) {
    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    fun providesLocalisationRepository(): LocalisationRepository {
        return localisationComponent.localisationRepository() // Provided by Localisation module with Dagger
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    fun providesConfigurationRepository(): ConfigurationRepository {
        return configurationComponent.configurationRepository() // Provided by Configuration module with Dagger
    }
}
```

Finally my Main Application

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        this.registerDependencies()
    }

    private fun registerDependencies() {
        val coreModule = CoreModule(applicationContext)
        val applicationModule = ApplicationModule(LocalisationModule(coreModule).localisationComponent,
                                ConfigurationModule(coreModule).configurationComponent)

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(applicationModule)
                .build()
    }
}
```

I pointed out that everything is working like a charm.